# Dask : how the memory limit is calculated in "auto" mode?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

The documentation shows the following formula in case of "auto" mode :

`$ dask-worker .. --memory-limit=auto  # TOTAL_MEMORY * min(1, nthreads / total_nthreads)`

My CPU spec :

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
```

My memory spec :

```
MemTotal:       16282416 kB
MemFree:         1142108 kB
MemAvailable:    9397036 kB
```

When I trigger the `dask_worker` command, the following output is displayed :

```
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -               Threads:                          1
distributed.worker - INFO -                Memory:                   3.88 GiB
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
```

Could you please explain, how `3.88 GiB memory` is found ? It seems to mismatch with the previous formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `nthreads` refers to how many threads *this* particular worker has available to schedule tasks on while `total_nthreads` refers to the total number of threads available on your system.

The `dask-worker` CLI command  has the same defaults as `LocalCluster` (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/4377)). Assuming the defaults for `LocalCluster` spin up `n` workers where `n` is the number of available cores on your system and assign `m` threads to each worker where `m` is the number of threads per core:

```
n = 4 # number of cores 
m = 1 # number of threads per core 

TOTAL_MEMORY = 16282416 kB

TOTAL_MEMORY * min(1, 1 / 4)

> 4070604
```

4070604 kB is 3.79 GiB

See the docs here:

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/deploying-cli.html#dask-worker

> --nthreads
>
> Number of threads per process.
>
> --nprocs
>
> Deprecated. Use ‘–nworkers’ instead. Number of worker processes to
> launch. If negative, then (CPU_COUNT + 1 + nprocs) is used. Set to
> ‘auto’ to set nprocs and nthreads dynamically based on CPU_COUNT
>
> --nworkers <n_workers>
>
> Number of worker processes to launch. If negative, then (CPU_COUNT +
> 1 + nworkers) is used. Set to ‘auto’ to set nworkers and nthreads
> dynamically based on CPU_COUNT

Also see the [source](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/main/distributed/deploy/local.py#L185-L197) for `LocalCluster` for how the defaults are set: